# How to insert unique values from object to array in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following object

```
0: {Dep_key: 1, sex: 2, dep: "HR department", Staff_name: "Hassan", 
    Staff_Key: 782, …}
1: {Dep_key: 1, sex: 2, dep: "sales department", Staff_name: "Ahmed", 
    Staff_Key: 813, …}
2: {Dep_key: 1, sex: 2, dep: "Marketing", Staff_name: "Hossam", 
    Staff_Key: 817, …}
```

and I want to insert a unique values of `Dep_key`(s) to an array. 
What I did

```
$scope.leftdept = function (m) {

        console.log(m);

        for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.depts.indexOf(m[i].Dep_key) === -1) {
                $scope.depts.push(m[i].Dep_key);
            }
            else {
                var index = $scope.depts.indexOf(m);
                $scope.depts.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }

       console.log($scope.depts);
    }
```

but my code is not inserting all `Dep_key`. Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: can you share logs of this `console.log(m);`

Comment: thanks for replying , i edited the question and shared it at the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the unique `Dep_key` you can remove your `else` block
You are inserting the "new" `Dep_key` in your `if` block the first time that appears, but then if the same `Dep_key` is present in the loop, in the `else` clause you're removing it. When you have 2 `Dep_key` in your array, you'll never obtain it in the output. Also, you're obtaining the `var index = $scope.depts.indexOf(m);` for the `m` array instead the `m[i]`, but as I said you can only have the `if` and the code should work

```
$scope.leftdept = function (m) {

    console.log(m);

    for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.depts.indexOf(m[i].Dep_key) === -1) {
            $scope.depts.push(m[i].Dep_key);
        }
    }

   console.log($scope.depts);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much , it works fine. i just have a question what if the end user want to uncheck department , how can i remove it from the pushed array, great thanks

Comment: I don't have the full code in front of me but I recommend you in that case to create a dedicated function and use something like `$scope.depts.slice(index,1)` where the `index` should be the one that corresponds to the unchecked one. Remember to mark the question as answered if it's okay for you. Thanks